# Laravel 7.2, composer install, don't install xethron/migrations-generator

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-7

I want to create a migration from existing database in Laravel 7.2.
I found xethron/migrations-generator in this [link](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator).
When I tried to install it I got this error:

```
Problem 1
- xethron/migrations-generator v2.0.0 requires way/generators dev-feature/laravel-five-stable -> no matching package found.
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.25.0
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.25.0
- xethron/migrations-generator v2.0.1 requires xethron/laravel-4-generators ~3.1.0 -> satisfiable by xethron/laravel-4-generators[3.1.0, 3.1.1].
- xethron/migrations-generator v2.0.2 requires xethron/laravel-4-generators ~3.1.0 -> satisfiable by xethron/laravel-4-generators[3.1.0, 3.1.1].
- xethron/laravel-4-generators 3.1.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
- xethron/laravel-4-generators 3.1.1 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
- illuminate/support 5.2.x-dev conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.25.0].
- illuminate/support 5.3.x-dev conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.25.0].
- illuminate/support 5.4.x-dev conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.25.0].
- illuminate/support 5.5.x-dev conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.25.0].
- illuminate/support v5.2.43 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.25.0].
- illuminate/support v5.2.45 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.25.0].
- illuminate/support v5.3.0 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.25.0].
- illuminate/support v5.3.16 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.25.0].
- illuminate/support v5.3.23 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.25.0].
- illuminate/support v5.3.4 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.25.0].
- illuminate/support v5.4.0 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.25.0].
- illuminate/support v5.4.13 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.25.0].
- illuminate/support v5.4.17 conflicts with laravel/framework[v7.25.0].
...
```

I tried `composer require --dev "kitloong/laravel-migrations-generator"` I got a similar error.

Comment: can you provide the lines before this ... particularly the first few lines after "Problem 1"

Comment: Done. I putted them.

Comment: you can't use that package with Laravel 7 ... what is the issue with the `kitloong` package?

Comment: Similar `Problem 1
    - xethron/migrations-generator v2.0.0 requires way/generators dev-feature/laravel-five-stable -> no matching package found.
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.25.0 ...`

Comment: remove `xethron/migrations-generator` from your `composer.json` ... the `kitloong` package does not use that, so that error is not because of it, it is because of the `xethron` package still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on https://packagist.org/packages/xethron/migrations-generator, this package is pretty old and most probably not compatible with Laravel v7.

`kitloong/laravel-migrations-generator` is a fork of that package, and according to their release notes, it should work up to Laravel v8. To make it work, you have to remove the other migrations generator first and install only the forked package.